# How to iterate over Django dict

Tags: python, django

Basically I need to iterate a certain dict from a queryset to be rendered on a template:

I used this:

```
top_donors = Donation.objects.values('donator').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

which basically gets a sum of each donator's total amount donated. i believe this returns a dict. i.e

```
[{'donator' : 3, 'amount_sum' : 5200}, {'donator' : 2, 'amount_sum' : 1200}, {.....}]
```

is there a better way to get that query? if not, i need to iterate over those and display it in a table. i.e

```
name   total amount
3        5200
2        1200
```

what are my options, thank you very much!

Comment: i tried that already but for some reason it does not work. :(

Comment: furthermore, when i use the python django shell. i get the error 'ValuesQuerySet' object has no attribute 'items'. so i think its not a viable option?

Comment: Yes, sorry , didn't look at your data structure close enough!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as given below  . it will work sure

```
{% for i in top_donors  %}
   {{ i.donator }}
   {{ i.amount__sum }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: woah. it worked! i dont understand. i remember trying this. @_@
thanks!

Comment: You must using single underscore as i saw amount_sum  in your dictionary .

Comment: oh i remember now, i used i.name and i.amount. which is in reference to their models. thank you.